# Hall-effect sensor datasheet/setup questions

Tags: sensor, hall-effect

I have a few [HO 6-P/SP33](https://www.lem.com/sites/default/files/products_datasheets/ho-p_sp33.pdf) Hall-effect sensors and I've been reading through the datasheet, but I can't figure out how I'm supposed to use them.

I have several questions about the information in the datasheet, mainly the below picture. (This is my first time using one of these, so I don't really know what I'm doing.)

[image: Operation Principal of HO 6-p/SP33]

- Do I have to set up the capacitors and the >10 kΩ resistor or are they built into the sensor?
- Why is the Vref labeled as (IN/OUT)? Other parts of the datasheet seem to indicate that Vref is only an input, not an output.
- What is the OCD pin? I don't see it mentioned anywhere else in the datasheet.
- The current I want to measure is around 80 mA, will this sensor be able to pick that up?

If anyone can answer any of these questions it would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***Do I have to set up the capacitors and the >10 kΩ resistor or are they built into the sensor?***

Yes, you need the bypass capacitors.  The 10 kΩ resistor is optional, only needed if you need the overcurrent detect feature.

***Why is the Vref labeled as (IN/OUT)? Other parts of the datasheet seem to indicate that Vref is only an input, not an output.***

It looks like (based on the IN/OUT) that the part has an internal reference, that comes out on Uref.  It also seems you can drive that pin to override the internal reference.  The datasheet is poorly written, so it leaves you to guess a bit on this.
[image]

***What is the OCD pin? I don't see it mentioned anywhere else in the datasheet.***

The OCD pin is an open-collector output for the overcurrent detect feature:
[image]

***The current I want to measure is around 80 mA, will this sensor be able to pick that up?***

This sensor is meant for currents of 6 A full scale, you can measure 80 mA with it, but the measurement will likely be noisy.  It seems like a mismatch, so you might want to look for a sensor with a range closer to your desired current value.

Comment: Wonderful, thanks for your help. I do have one follow up question, if I wrap a wire through the sensor multiple times could I increase the effective current to get it into the range of the sensor?

Comment: @Royginald Yes, that is an effective technique, but it still seems like your sensor is mismatched to your current range.  (Especially if the current can go significantly lower than 80 mA.

Comment: This technique works with CT, But remember you have to "fix" wires ... and make a calibration because "position" can change "characteristics" (a little ...).